# FQL Unlike keep showing page like is true

Tags: php, api, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

I am using following fql to find out if page is liked or not:

```
 $fql_query_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'
    . 'fql?q=SELECT+uid,page_id+FROM+page_fan+WHERE+uid=me()+AND+page_id=' . $pageId
    . '&access_token=' . $facebook->getAccessToken();

  $fql_query_result = file_get_contents($fql_query_url);

  $fql_query_obj = json_decode($fql_query_result, true);

  if($fql_query_obj['data'][0]['uid']!=''){

      $isFan = true;
//      echo "<h1> Is Fan </h1>";

  } else {
      $isFan = false;
  }

 //var_dump($isFan);
```

Last line every time return true, even after disliking using page tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [Graph API Explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) to find out if page_id exist or not, it returned empty data. Then I tried to access all the pages user is fan. I saw that current page id was there, it clearly explain that there are some issues with graph api.

One solution of my problem is to loop through all the page_id and check if current page_id exist in it.

Remember that you must convert page_id to float first. To match it within the loop as facebook return ids as float when don't fit in int.

```
if($fql_query_obj['data'][$i]['page_id']==(float)$pageId) // page is liked :)
```

2nd method is to query by quoting your page_id in quotes, i.e.

```
$fql_query_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'

. 'fql?q=SELECT+uid,page_id+FROM+page_fan+WHERE+uid=me()+AND+page_id=\'' . $pageId

. '\'&access_token=' . $facebook->getAccessToken();
```